# How to Configure android app properties in eclipse so that I can send email automatically?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, email

I want to send email from my app automatically in eclipse as a user press button I tried all possible suggestions found on the Internet added jar files like javax.mail.jar, activation.jar, and additional.jar and tried all possible ways to add them but  always produce error.
I did hard work but with no result I really got tired.
I tried code on java project it worked and send email successfully but in android project it does not   and here is code snippet:

```
`Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");        
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
     session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new  Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
                }
            });

     test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         try {

                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("dev.montaser@gmail.com"));
                message.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse("eng.montaser99@yahoo.com"));
                message.setSubject("Test JCG Example");
                message.setContent("Hello how are you","text/html; charset=utf-8");

                Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("Mail sent succesfully!");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }               
        }
    });


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

and here is error log.
    03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.finalp.MainActivity$1
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at com.example.finalp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-29 15:16:00.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

`

Comment: I want to tell you that I work on Linux OS (mint)

Comment: I think the easiest way to do it is to get a free account with a mail provider and use that to send mail.  There are several that let you just make an HTTP call to send mail so you don't have to deal with javamail, which I'm not sure is well supported on Android.